# ¿en php qué significa $variable = $variable2 = " ";?

Tags: php, php7, variables, operador

¿Qué significa o cómo se puede interpretar? lo siguiente:

```
$name = $email = $edad = $comentario = "";
```

Sé que son variables pero no entiendo por que usar el signo de = y al final ""

Comment: Es algo simple y sencillamente básico en programación php y en todos los lenguajes de alto nivel. Debes de declarar las variables y asignarles un valor (usando "="), ya sea "" (el que mencionas), un número, una cadena de texto o null, etc.

Comment: Se llama inicialización de variables; y la cadena vacía no siempre es la mejor opción para eso.

Answer (score 1):

Se lee de izquierda a derecha.

```
$comentario = "";
```

es una expresión que asigna "" a `$comentario` y devuelve "".

Con lo cual,

```
$edad = $comentario = "";
```

primero asigna "" a `$comentario` y luego asigna el resultado de la expresión ("") a `$edad`.

Todo lo cual se repite hasta que a todas las variables de la lista se les ha asignado "".

Comment: oye pero la duda es ¿qué significa ""? ¿qué valor tiene eso?

Comment: El uso de comillas doble significa que le asignas un valor VACIO. Destaco VACIO por que algo VACIO no es igual a NULL o CERO. Depende de como manejes el valor en todo caso.

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta rapida: Para declarar multiples variables con el mismo valor, lo que hace ese codigo es lo siguiente:

```
$name = "";
$email = "";
$edad = "";
$comentario = "";
```

Como ves, esta declarando el valor `""` (Un valor vacio) a todas las variables, asi que esa es su funcionalidad. Un ejemplo seria lo siguiente:

```
$name = $email = $edad = $comentario = "Hola";
```

Lo anterior es lo mismo que escribir esto:

```
$name = "Hola";
$email = "Hola";
$edad = "Hola";
$comentario = "Hola";
```

Con esto te ahorras lineas de codigo si quieres que muchas variables tengan el mismo valor

Comment: Ok la duda es  ¿qué significa ""?

Comment: Significa que al declarar esa variable le asignas temporalmente un valor vacío y que más adelante le volverías asignar otro valor sea por un valor que viene de la base de datos, un variable de sesión, un valor que vendría de un POST, etc.